# Tensorflow save/restore batch norm

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

I trained a model with batch norm in Tensorflow. I would like to save the model and restore it for further using. The batch norm is done by

```
def batch_norm(input, phase):
    return tf.layers.batch_normalization(input, training=phase)
```

where the phase is `True` during training and `False` during testing.

It seems like simply calling

```
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.save(sess, savedir + "ckpt")
```

would not work well because when I restore the model it first says restored successfully. It also says `Attempting to use uninitialized value batch_normalization_585/beta` if I just run one node in the graph. Is this related to not saving the model properly or something else that I've missed?

Comment: might be related to naming mismatches of the restored and saved model batch normalization layer

Comment: Is there any chance to fix this?

Comment: you can import the graph `tf.import_meta_graph` and restore the model there after.

Comment: Thanks for helping me! I'll try that after this side question: do I need to define the graph like the original training graph? Or I can just open a session and the importing op will reorganize the graph for me?

Comment: you can read the docs of `tf.import_meta_graph`, here you need your checkpoint .meta file as input, then just restore the session with checkpoint file.

Comment: The `tf.import_meta_graph` has been hanging for almost 30 minutes. I followed the docs, but still it seems like I missed something.

Comment: it should be something like this: `saver = tf.import_meta_graph(/path/to/checkpoint.meta_file)` `saver.restore(sess, /path/to/checkpoint)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152468/discussion-between-aleex-and-ishant-mrinal).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I also had the "Attempting to use uninitialized value batch_normalization_585/beta" error. This comes from the fact that by declaring the saver with the empty brackets like this:

```
         saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

The saver will save the variables contained in tf.trainable_variables() which do not contain the moving average of the batch normalization. To include this variables into the saved ckpt you need to do:

```
         saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
```

Which saves ALL the variables, so it is very memory consuming. Or you must identify the variables that have moving avg or variance and save them by declaring them like:

```
         saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.trainable_variables() + list_of_extra_variables)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you mentioned explicitly what to put in `list_of_extra_variables` if one wants to restore the moving averages.

Comment: I believe it would be `bn.moving_mean` and `bn. moving_variance` if your batch norm layer is `bn`.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this needs to be explained, but just in case (and for other potential viewers).

Whenever you create an operation in TensorFlow, a new node is added to the graph. No two nodes in a graph can have the same name. You can define the name of any node you create, but if you don't give a name, TensorFlow will pick one for you *in a deterministic way* (that is, not randomly, but instead always with the same sequence). If you add two numbers, it will probably be `Add`, but if you do another addition, since no two nodes can have the same name, it may be something like `Add_2`. Once a node is created in a graph its name cannot be changed. Many functions create several subnodes in turn; for example, `tf.layers.batch_normalization` creates some internal variables `beta` and `gamma`.

Saving and restoring works in the following way:

1. You create a graph representing the model that you want. This graph contains the variables that will be saved by the saver.
2. You initialize, train or do whatever you want with that graph, and the variables in the model get assigned some values.
3. You call `save` on the saver to, well, save the values of the variables to a file.
4. Now you recreate the model *in a different graph* (it can be a different Python session altogether or just another graph coexisting with the first one). The model must be created in exactly the same way the first one was.
5. You call `restore` on the saver to retrieve the values of the variables.

In order for this to work, the names of the variables in the first and the second graph must be **exactly the same**.

In your example, TensorFlow is complaining about the variable `batch_normalization_585/beta`. It seems that you have called `tf.layers.batch_normalization` nearly 600 times in the same graph, so you have that many `beta` variables hanging around. I doubt that you actually need that many, so I guess you are just experimenting with the API and ended up with that many copies.

Here's a draft of something that should work:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def make_model():
    input = tf.placeholder(...)
    phase = tf.placeholder(...)
    input_norm = tf.layers.batch_normalization(input, training=phase))
    # Do some operations with input_norm
    output = ...
    saver = tf.train.Saver()
    return input, output, phase, saver

# We work with one graph first
g1 = tf.Graph()
with g1.as_default():
    input, output, phase, saver = make_model()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        # Do your training or whatever...
        saver.save(sess, savedir + "ckpt")

# We work with a second different graph now
g2 = tf.Graph()
with g2.as_default():
    input, output, phase, saver = make_model()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        saver.restore(sess, savedir + "ckpt")
        # Continue using your model...
```

Again, the typical case is not to have two graphs side by side, but rather have one graph and then recreate it in another Python session later, but in the end both things are the same. The important part is that the model is created in the same way (and therefore with the same node names) in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What I did was that I opened a session to restore the variables under the same graph in another script, I thought that would be sufficient to define the graph again and restore the variables. I did this before with another model, and it worked well, so I still don't know why it doesn't work now. Plus I found it wired I have called almost 600 times tf.layers.batch_normalization because I only want around 150 of them.

Comment: I tried your implementation, there was a glitch with my version. Basically my input was done with a pipeline rather than a placeholder to feed in the data. I included the whole pipeline into the function of making model, but it gave me `ValueError: Tensor("random_shuffle_queue_EnqueueMany/component_1:0", shape=(80000, 300), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("random_shuffle_queue:0", shape=(), dtype=resource).
`
Please help me with this.

Comment: @ALeex I don't have much experience with input pipelines, but, like the error message says, you are trying to use an object created in one graph in a different graph, which is not possible. All the objects in a model must be created within the same graph (either the default one or one that you manually create with `tf.Graph`).